# DataTables when choosing "All" in "Show Entries", No matching records found

Tags: javascript

Hello i am setting up my first DataTable and i like it very much. Everything works perfect except the All choice in te Show Entries dropdown. It show's nothing when i choose that (**No matching records found**) The other numbers do work perfectly.

I use this code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#empTable').DataTable({
  aLengthMenu: [
                 [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
                 [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
             ],
                'processing': true,
                'serverSide': true,
                'serverMethod': 'post',
                'ajax': {
                    'url':'ajaxfile.php'
                },
                'columns': [
                    { data: 'last_name' },
                    { data: 'email' },
                    { data: 'gender' },
                    { data: 'first_name' },
                    { data: 'city' },
                ],
                dom: 'lBfrtip',
             buttons: [
                 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf','print'
             ],
            });
        });
```

Comment: Not too sure about this misfunction since we dont have your actual table with data but try changing aLengthMenu to "lengthMenu" and give it a go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `ajaxfile.php` you have used a `limit()` for limiting the record and that get the values like `25, 50, 100, 200`, but for `All` it value is `-1` means the query is like:

```
.... limit(-1);
```

That's why it is showing **No matching records found**.

Make some changes in your logic so that when you get All i.e. `-1` as limit parameter, don't use the `limit()` in that case and fetch all records otherwise use it.

Try this, it will resolve the issue.

Comment: So i have to write PHP like if $limit == -1 { Show infinite records } ? The  Value if i choose All is "-1" then?

Comment: $limit == -1, then don't use `limit()` in that case it will return all records.

Comment: Aight i got you, will try it. Will let you know if it worked

Comment: I can't figure it out, i am a beginner. `## Fetch records
$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM clientInformation WHERE 1 ".$searchQuery." ORDER BY ".$columnName." ".$columnSortOrder." LIMIT :limit,:offset");

// Bind values
foreach($searchArray as $key=>$search){
    $stmt->bindValue(':'.$key, $search,PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

$stmt->bindValue(':limit', (int)$row, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':offset', (int)$rowperpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();` What to do?